# Why is Config.groovy variable not defined in plugin's config?

Tags: grails, configuration, grails-plugin

I have a Grails app (`myapp`) that uses a custom plugin (`grails-fizz`). In `myapp`'s `Config.groovy` I have the following var defined:

```
logfile = "/opt/myapp/logs/myapp.log"
```

I then pull in `grails-fizz` as a plugin inside the app's `BuildConfig.groovy` file. In `grails-fizz`'s `FizzGrailsPlugin.groovy`, I try to use that value:

```
def doWithApplicationContext = { ctx ->
    println("The logfile is ${logfile}.")
}
```

When this runs I get the following error:

> Error initializing the application: No such property: logfile for class: FizzGrailsPlugin

It seems that the plugin doesn't have scope/visibility over this var? What's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can access configuration values through the configuration object.

```
def doWithApplicationContext = { ctx ->
  def config = ctx.config
  println println "The logfile is ${config.logfile}."
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joshua Moore (+1) - what about inside the plugin's `Config.groovy`? Is it possible to get access to the `logfile` variable inside it? If so, how? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/plugins.html#evaluatingConventions)

> Every plugin has an implicit `application` variable which is an instance of the GrailsApplication interface.

So you can use `application.config` to access the configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Ian Roberts (+1) - would I have access to this `application` instance from inside the plugin's `Config.groovy` as well?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja the plugin's own `Config.groovy` is only used when you do `run-app` within the plugin itself (i.e. run the plugin as if it were an app).  It is ignored when the plugin is used by another application.  It's the top-level application that is responsible for the configuration at runtime.

Comment: Thanks again @Ian Roberts (+1) - Let's say I want to use the plugin to configure my log4j logging for the Grails app, and then omit any log4j configurations in the app (thus allowing the plugin's log4j to take precedence)...where inside the plugin should I put the typical `log4j { ... }` closure to accomplish this?

Comment: Perhaps the `doWithApplication` closure is the best place for this? Can I add the `log4j` closure here?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja it sounds like you're fighting against Grails here rather than working with it.  The way Grails works the _application_ sets up the config which the _plugins_ can then react to, not the other way around.  A plugin would typically hard code its own default settings but allow the app to override those in the config if necessary.